# How to submit the button with out clicking on any element or button in the android phone?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, appium-android

Hi I have to submit the password in the android phone to go to next page but i don't have any locators to click on the submit button.

I have to press the soft key i.e 'Done'?

How to submit the password with out clicking on any element in the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
Password.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //Start activity here


                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

You can do it in this way

Answer (score 0):

You could just click the button by using it's text.
http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Click%20Text

Example...

```
Click Text  Submit
```

Comment: it;s don't have any locator and it's don't have 'Done' button.

Comment: I get you. You updated your question. Maybe 'adb shell input keyevent 66'
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER. Essentially, you can use adb to interact with the phone and send keys. See if ENTER works and then just use that.

Comment: sorry.it's not working with 'adb shell input keyevent 66'

Comment: You say not working. What happens ? Your phone is connected to the Mac/PC...you are able to use your keyboard to interact with the app right ?

Comment: i want to press on the phone keypad